# opc hda - History Read, issue with continuationPoint when trying to read in batches

Tags: opc-ua, opc

I have connected to OPC HDA Server using OPC milo java SDK and trying to read history in batches for single node by passing `numValuesPerNode` as 15 to `ReadRawModifiedDetails(..)` to read only 15 data values in batches. But I have noticed `continuationPoint` is null. I want to set this `continuationPoint` to read remaining data values nodes. this will be in loop to read 15 data values in batches. Below is the code.  Can you please help to read data values in batches and `continuationPoint` having values?

```
    HistoryReadDetails historyDetails = new ReadRawModifiedDetails(
            false,
            dateStart,
            dateEnd,
            UInteger.valueOf(15),
            true
    );
    HistoryReadValueId nodeId= new HistoryReadValueId(
            new NodeId(1, 22),
            null,
            QualifiedName.NULL_VALUE,
            ByteString.NULL_VALUE
    );
    List<HistoryReadValueId> nodesToRead = new ArrayList<>();
    nodesToRead.add(nodeId);
    HistoryReadResponse historyReadResponse = client.historyRead(
            historyReadDetails,
            TimestampsToReturn.Both,
            false,
            nodesToRead
    ).get();

    HistoryReadResult[] historyReadResults = historyReadResponse.getResults();
```

Here `historyReadResults` returning `continuationPoint` as null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a miss understanding on your side.
ContinuationPoints are created from the server, if they can't supply all values in on request. It's not designed to get the next values.

- Either you read all at once, the server will generate ContinuationPoints , if it's limit is exceed.
- Or modifiy dateStart to be later then the last value from the previous call.

Comment: Thanks it clarifies my doubt. Suppose i have 10000 nodes and want to read history data for all. Do you know how many parallel history read calls to OPC ha server is supported using opcclient.

Comment: You can have read history for multiple nodes at once. Also there a server nodes in the addressspace, where where most server exposes their limits.

Comment: How will i know server exposed the limits. what is the minimum limit at server side on accepting history read calls. During implementation if there are 10000 nodes, i might make 10000 history read calls at once, how can i make limited history read calls

Answer (score 0):

The `numValuesPerNode` parameter of the `ReadRawModifiedDetails` structure isn't for reading in batches, it's to tell the server you're only interested in a certain number data points.

> The maximum number of values returned for any Node over the time range. If only one time is specified, the time range shall extend to return this number of values. The default value 0 indicates that there is no maximum.

https://reference.opcfoundation.org/Core/Part11/v104/docs/6.4.3

Comment: then what is the mechanism for reading HistoryData in batches

Comment: Continuation Points, but you don't decide when it happens as a client. It happens when you ask for more data than can be returned in a single response, based on the agreed upon message sizes between client/server and any server-specific configuration. The server will return a non-null Continuation Point if you need to make another call to get the rest of the data.

Comment: Can we define message sizes from client to server, by which server can respond based on message size. Also any performance improvement code doc or blog that will help in reading history data for large no of nodes and history data values in java.